# How to count orders of products that have pending status in Woocommerce?

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, count, orders

I'm trying to make stats script that makes clear usage for reservations of product for Woocommerce, diplaying available, reserved, and sold status. Status orders are available in backend admin panel, but I need to make count and visible in frontend.

Example:

> ProductName
>
> Items available: 10
>
> **Items already reserved (but not paid yet): X**
>
> Items sold: Y

Currently woocommerce has a function that shows sold quantity per product, but it counts both reserved (pending status) and sold (completed), so it's different kind of count.

I wrote a query that should find orders matching pending status (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = **46**) but I can't select only one specific  product, as it counts all pending orders in database. The product ID is the same for wp_posts.ID and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = **250**.

Note that product and orders are in the same table: **wp_posts**.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wp_posts.ID) 
FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oi 

WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
AND oi.meta_key = '_product_id'
AND oi.meta_value = 250
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 46
```

Any ideas how to select count for only this one product? I feel I need just one more filer but can't figure out what is missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to count based on the product id? `select ID, COunt(*) from .................. group by id`

Comment: I tried, but stil gave wrong rows count, result is actually the same, added column with count, but I have no idea what is counted here.

Comment: I suppose that something is wrong with the meta filter (key, value), but these seem to be correct, but not working, and that's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Just as I suspected I needed one more table to be filtered, and that did the whole trick!

So the line that was missing: **ii.order_id = wp_posts.ID**, and some other tweaks ;)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wp_posts.ID) 

FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oi, wp_woocommerce_order_items ii 

WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = (xx - order status id) 
AND  wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
AND oi.order_item_id = ii.order_item_id
AND oi.meta_key = '_product_id'
AND oi.meta_value = (yy - specific product id, the same id as in wp_posts)
AND ii.order_id = wp_posts.ID
AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

Make sure not to select 'shop_order" post type since it will give wrong result :) and note, that complete status may have few more values, since woocommerce has different state values for completed, removed, paid, and canceled order.

I hope this will be helpful to someone else :)

And many thanks to **Kiril** for guiding me to this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following and give it a go. It might need a few adjustments
UPDATED:

```
     SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oi 

  WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
  AND wp_posts.ID= oi.meta_id
 AND oi.metakey = '_product_id'
 AND oi.metavalue = 250
 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
 AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
 AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 46
```

Comment: Just edited your answer and pasted query that you were suggesting.

Comment: A quick question, do u have a field which contains `ORDER id` information inside the `wp_term_relationships`?

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04e1c/1) I have reproduced your example as much as I could, and I got the right count. You shoud be counting the `order_ids` not the `productID`

Comment: In wp_term_relationships there is a main key object_id which is also ID of the order from wp_posts, and there is also a shared key term_taxonomy_id which indicates the current state of the order.

All tables are default woocommerce and wordpress tables, no custom tables.

To be clear: "order_id" is actually ID key from wp_posts, and the same key indicates both product and order, they are just different rows (in our example ID= 250  is a product row)

Comment: then use `wp_posts.ID= oi.meta_id` in your where clause and specify `Count(*)` instead. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c703d2/1

Comment: I'll check out your  Fiddle further. Maybe I can copy my base so the results would be as similiar as possible.

Comment: **oi.meta_id** is a regular key and does not match any other table. **oi.meta_value** is the shared kwy woth the product.

Well, tried solution given on fiddle, but the query result gave me 0 results, so modified the fiddle, you will be able to see how the ID's are matched, I tried to make it as similiar as possible. Result is the same on both fiddlle and my base ;)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c4181/1/0

Comment: I dont get it because I think it works in the way it is supposed to: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c4181/8 ; if you have `metavalue=289`  it starts counting all records with `wp_posts.ID= 289`

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinformed you, values in itemmeta were wrong, there should be PRODUCT ID numbers (25, 24, 16), not order ID's. I corrected that, sorry again. Been trudging through this query since 3 days and already going nuts :) Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75e2ea/2/0

Comment: ok but in your question you are stating that: `The product ID is the same for wp_posts.ID and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = 25.` I cant see any records with `wo_posts.ID=25`, therefore the count is 0

Comment: In the last fiddle I corrected wp_posts, should be 6 rows, 3 orders and 3 products (tehre is one - 25 - the filter for "published" should be removed since there is no such value for product in this example). Running this query with published filter removed still gives other than expected result. 

I think I found the missing link here, completely forgot about one table with ordered items, which holds the primary key: order_item_id, which is also in itemmmeta table within each row and meta_value. I think its the right way to solve the missing element.

Comment: Will post my (hopefully working) solution when its done, for future reference :) Thanks a lot Kiril for your time, skill and patience.

Comment: @user3074005 I am glad you found your way around this and I am sorry that I couldnt help.